# How to find row number and column number of a specific element in a multi dimensional array created with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

In a multi-dimensional array created using numpy in python like

```
matrix=np.array[[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

if we were to treat it as matrix. Is there any way to find the row number and column number of element `'1'` or any other specific element inside the matrix?

Comment: Use np.where() ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use *np.argwhere*:

```
np.argwhere(matrix == 1)
```

but note that your array can contain **multiple** elements with just this value,
so it returns a *2-D* array, where each row contains indices of each element found.

If you want **only the first** such element, run:

```
np.argwhere(matrix == 1)[0]
```

This time you will get a *1-D* array, containing 2 element (row and column number).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion btw, i improved it a bit like if u do `np.where(matrix==1)` the output will be in tuples and we can retrieve both values of row and column by tuple unpacking `res=np.where(matrix==1)` and `(a,b)=res` then we can use 'a' and 'b' individually